# How do I iterate through nested properties of an json object and create a new array list?

Tags: javascript, json

I have an json object 'items' and i'm trying to get all the 'values' into a separate string:

```
 "items":[  
      {  
         "id":0,
         "categoryId":0,
         "label":"TOTAL EDUCATION",
         "total":739599,
         "values":[  
            451383,
            288216
         ],
         "items":[  ],
         "metadataIds":"20006",
         "collapsed":true
      },
      {  
         "id":0,
         "categoryId":0,
         "label":"TOTAL HIGHWAYS",
         "total":63678,
         "values":[  
            32672,
            31006
         ],
         "items":[  ],
         "metadataIds":"20022",
         "collapsed":true
      },

for (var i = 0; i < obj.items.length; i++) {
        var cost = obj.items[i].values;
    }
```

the output i'm trying to achieve from the values:

[451383,288216],[32672,31006] etc.

Example here:https://jsfiddle.net/zidski/6mg8fszj/

Currently I can only output 1 of the 'values' set.

Comment: By the time you're iterating, you're not dealing with JSON anymore. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, is there a short cut for JSON claimer?

Comment: @NinaScholz: *I* have one (a bookmarklet): http://pastie.org/10803470 Open the comment area, choose that bookmark, edit as appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Currently I can only output 1 of the 'values' set.

Well, yes; you're overwriting it every time.

You've said you want "one string," and the output you've shown has `[` and `]` in it. Amusingly, while you're not dealing with JSON when iterating, JSON can play a role in producing that string:

```
var str = obj.items.map(function(item) {
    return JSON.stringify(item.values);
}).join(",");
```

`Array#map` loops through `items` building a new array out of what we return for each item from our callback; in the above, we're returning the JSON string equivalent of each item's `values` array. Then we `join` the resulting array with commas in-between to get the final string.

**Example:**

```js
var obj = {
  "items": [{
    "id": 0,
    "categoryId": 0,
    "label": "TOTAL EDUCATION",
    "total": 739599,
    "values": [
      451383,
      288216
    ],
    "items": [],
    "metadataIds": "20006",
    "collapsed": true
  }, {
    "id": 0,
    "categoryId": 0,
    "label": "TOTAL HIGHWAYS",
    "total": 63678,
    "values": [
      32672,
      31006
    ],
    "items": [],
    "metadataIds": "20022",
    "collapsed": true
  }]
};
var str = obj.items.map(function(item) {
        return JSON.stringify(item.values);
    }).join(",");
document.body.innerHTML =
  "<pre>" + str + "</pre>";
```

If you *don't* actually want a string, but instead you want an array of arrays, it's a bit simpler:

```
var arrayOfArrays = obj.items.map(function(item) {
    return item.values;
});
```

```js
var obj = {
  "items": [{
    "id": 0,
    "categoryId": 0,
    "label": "TOTAL EDUCATION",
    "total": 739599,
    "values": [
      451383,
      288216
    ],
    "items": [],
    "metadataIds": "20006",
    "collapsed": true
  }, {
    "id": 0,
    "categoryId": 0,
    "label": "TOTAL HIGHWAYS",
    "total": 63678,
    "values": [
      32672,
      31006
    ],
    "items": [],
    "metadataIds": "20022",
    "collapsed": true
  }]
};
var arrayOfArrays = obj.items.map(function(item) {
    return item.values;
});
// Just using JSON so we have text to show as a result
document.body.innerHTML =
  "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(arrayOfArrays, null, 2) + "</pre>";
```